# Differential of the inverse map gives rise to the bracket of vector fields being zero

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Suppose that $J:G\to G$ is the inverse map on a Lie group $G$ And suppose that $X,Y$ are vector fields. We know that if $\phi:G\to G$ is an arbitrary diffeomorphism then $d\phi[X,Y]=[d\phi X, d\phi Y]$. Hence since $J$ is a diffeomorphism this relation holds giving rise to the bracket of left invariant vector fields being zero whether $G$ is abelian or not. I know I am wrong but what is wrong with my argument?

Comment: You'll have to give your "argument" for this. How does it "[give] rise to the bracket of left invariant vector fields being zero"?

Comment: If the equality above is really correct, then $-[X,Y]=dJ[X,Y]=[dJ.X,dJ.Y]=[-X,-Y]=[X,Y]$. But I think that equality above is wrong. @TedShifrin

Comment: The inverse map is not a left translation in the group. So something that holds just at the identity doesn't hold elsewhere.

Comment: I didn’t use any thing except for 1) the equality above, and 2) that $dJ$ maps $X$ to $-X$. So I don’t know where I have possibly ignored the fact that the inverse map is not a left translation. @TedShifrin

Comment: $dJ$ only maps $X$ to $-X$ at the identity. In general, what's the formula for $dJ_g$?

Comment: Thanks I got it now, I’ll calculate $dJ$ @TedShifrin

Comment: It is $-dR_{g^{-1}}dL_{g^{-1}}$. I don’t know why I previously thought it was $X\mapsto -X$. @TedShifrin

Comment: There you go :)